# I can't add widgets to a fixed layout added to a Gtk.Dialog

Tags: c#, mono, gtk#, xamarin-studio

I want write my first application using Xamarin Studio and GTK#. I have MainWindow.cs and I can add container Fixed, I can place anywhere buttons. But main window must not be Fixed, and rather modal dialog must has fixed layout.
I create new file Dialog.cs: public partial class Dialog : Gtk.Dialog
I add Fixed and can't add buttons, **why**? 
I must use  class Window : Gtk.Window instead of Dialog and show modal this window?

Comment: Could you try to improve your question it's quite hard for me to grasp what you are asking?

Comment: When I have Dialog and place Fixed, i can't place other widgets

Answer (score 1):

There could be a bunch of things wrong here. So let's start with the basics first. As you named your dialog `Dialog` are you sure you are using your `YourNamespace.Dialog` and not the base class `Gtk.Dialog`. This would display an empty box. Try to specify your namespace explicitly to sort this out:

```
protected void SomeButtonHasClicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  using (var dialog = new Sample.Dialog ()) {
    var result = dialog.Run ();
    // so sth. with the result
  }
}
```

Do you have `AutoSize` disabled and `Expand` and `Fill` enabled in the fixed layouts properties, otherwise the layout just glues on the top of the dialog.

Comment: Container Fixed must has not Autosize but Expand and Fill